# Convergence of a seqence under the integral sign

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded domain.
Let $f\in L^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$ and a sequence $\left\{ f_{k}\right\} $
so that 
$$
f_{k}\rightarrow f
$$
uniformly on each compact subset of $\Omega.$ Assume $\intop_{\Omega}f_{k}=1$
for any $k.$ Can we conclude that 
$$
\intop_{\Omega}f=1?
$$

You may assume every function here is smooth on $\Omega$ if you want.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $\Omega=(0,1)$, $f_k(x)=k\cdot\mathbf 1_{(0,\frac1k)}$. Then you have $f_k\to f=0$ on each interval $[a,b]\subset(0,1)$, hence on compact subsets also. You also have $\int_\Omega f_k=1$ and $\int_\Omega f=0$.